# Using adverbs "generally" or "in general"

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Is there any difference between `Additionally,` and `In addition,` at the beginning of the sentence? The same question for `Generally,` and `In general,`. Some that using `ly` at the beginning is very formal and some say there is no difference. I want to use them in an academic research paper.

**P.S:** regarding `Additionally,` and `In addition,` I want to know is it ok to use `More than that,`?

Comment: I don’t think there is a difference between either pair. PS I think that “more than that” is fine, but you may also want to consider “moreover”.

Comment: Or "furthermore".

Comment: FWIW, I just came across a comment on my thesis where the professor has recommended that I begin a new sentence with “in addition”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally is seen as sloppy and informal as compared to "in addition". Its often used(in poor taste) as a replacement for "furthermore". Consider the sentences below:

- Additionally, I would like to propose a toast.
- In addition, I would like to propose a toast.
- Furthermore, I would like to propose a toast.

All sentences are valid, but the first is most sloppy, the second is in the middle, and the last is the best received of the three.

But given a sentence like this:

- I would like a faster car, in addition to a surround sound system.

In addition makes the most sense here.

The word "Additionally" should be avoided in nearly all situations if you want to be formal or sound more professional.

Response to Edit:

More than that, is fine but is somewhat verbose. Furthermore is your best bet.

Source: Im a native English speaker raised in the US, and this source backs up my beliefs:

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs4/grammarlogs579.htm

Comment: So the same rule applies to "Generally," and "In general,". Right?

Comment: I have nothing to back this up. But in my personal experience, those 2 dont make any difference.